# Please help me understand this proof.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, proof-explanation

Larger side / larger angle theorem:

Prop. I.18: In any triangle, the greater side is opposite the greater angle.

Proof: Assume not. Let angle $\angle ACB$ be greater than $\angle BAC$ and assume side AB is less than base BC. Extend side BA past A to X so that BX equals BC. Then in triangle BXC, sides BX and BC are equal so angles $\angle BCX = \angle BXC$. Now $\angle BAC$ is exterior to $\angle BXC$ hence $\angle BAC$ is greater. But $\angle BAC$ was assumed smaller than $\angle ACB = \angle BCX=\angle BXC$, a contradiction.

I just can't see how angle $\angle ACB = \angle BCX$. After I draw the diagram, it looks $\angle ACB$ is inside $\angle BCX$, therefore smaller than $\angle BCX$.

[image: The triangle I tried to draw to follow the proof]

Comment: Why is $<BAC$ [exterior to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles) $<BXC$. I can't see this.
Also I can't see that the exterior angel is the greater one. In the [picture of the wici article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ExternalAngles.svg) the exterior angle is the smaller one.

Comment: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI18.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture is not good because the angles all look the same. At least start by drawing a triangle where one side is visually much larger than the other sides. Also I think you have a typo: ACB should be less than BCX since it's an interior angle. This will give you a contradiction that BAC> BXC> ACB whereas you assumed BAC < ACB.

Comment: Can you elaborate why ACB should be less than BCX? Both are [interior angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles) of some triangles. Also I can't see how the property to be an interior anlge is related to it's size?